# CSS table not working changing when switching stylesheets

Tags: html, css

I am having some strange issues with the css table that I cannot figure out.
I am using the following to switch between stylesheets when the window becomes small. I was intending to change the arrangement of elements on the page when this occurs.

The index-large css makes profile and event appear side by side, while index- small css makes the events appear above profile. 
The problem is, when shrinking the browser, the transition happens correctly, and the profile becomes below the events, but when increasing the size again, the profile remains below the events.

My code is:

HTML:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = "index-screen-small.css" media="all and (min-device-width:1000px) and (max-width: 601px)">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = "index-screen-large.css" media="all and (min-device-width:1000px) and (min-width: 600px)">
...
<div id = "main">
<div id = events></div>
<div id = break></div>
<div id = profiles></div>
</div>
```

CSS: index-style-large:

```
#main{
   display = table;
}
#events{
   display = table-cell;
}
}
#break{
   display = none;
}
#profiles{
   display = table-cell;
}
```

CSS: index-style-small:

```
#main{
   display = table;
}
#events{
   display = table-cell;
}
}
#break{
   display = table-row;
}
#profiles{
   display = table-cell;
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: That might be the most backwards way to use media queries that I've ever seen.. I suggest you do some research into how media queries function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in your media queries.  Should be:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = "index-screen-small.css" media="all and (max-device-width:1000px) and (max-width: 600px)">
```

NOT:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href = "index-screen-small.css" media="all and (min-device-width:1000px) and (max-width: 601px)">
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just changed it to be 601 in an attempt to make it work. Thanks for the attempt though!